# What programming solution can one use, when a variable needs to take one of n unique, finite values, where n is greater then 2?

Tags: architecture, logic

For the sake of argument, let's assume that all of these values are completely unique, and cannot be defined by a range (less then x, but more then y).

For example, if I had to represent, let's say, a variable, whose value could either be an apple, or a banana. I could represent this variable with a boolean, and just assume that true means apples and false means bananas throughout my program. But what if that variable can take up three values, such as apples, bananas, and oranges?

One solution would be to wrap this around in a bean class, make it private, and then write a method that only allows you to set a value if it's one of these 'n' values, essentially adding a check.

Another solution can be to make an enumerated type.

But what else?

Comment: Why do you need a solution other than an enum?

Comment: I don't need another solution. What I'm asking is probably what enums were built for. This is basically a thought experiment.

Comment: If you can use a `boolean` to represent two options, where you know that a particular value represents a particular object, in your case a fruit, what about a `short` to represent 3 or more, or maybe a `byte`?

Comment: hmm, the thought did cross my mind. But we run into one problem very soon - since byte or short have a range of possible values, this would work if n was equal to that range. But if n is 3, and a signed byte goes from -128 to 127, then you need a check, some sort of filtering mechanism, because your variable can take up invalid values... maybe if you modded by n?

Answer (score 1):

Do *absolutely* not use *booleans* to represent something like this.

Booleans are for logical values; representing *true* and *false*. Nothing else. As soon as you get into the *true* means *Apple* and *false* means *Banana* business you are getting into the business that each and any code that needs to deal with "fruits" needs to understand this (arbitrary) mapping from boolean to Apple/Banana.

The correct solution in languages such as Java or C++ for such problems: [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). Ensure that the **compiler** understands the valid values for "objects" of such types; instead of inventing your *own* mapping!

Answer (score 0):

If, as you suggest, you can use a `boolean` to represent two options, where you know that a particular value represents a particular object, in your case a fruit (but without the ability to check that it is one of a specified range), then how about a `short` to represent 3 or more, or maybe a `byte`? Even a `char[]` or `string` would suffice.

However if you require the checking capability, then you would need an `enum` or a `class`.

However, you *could* use a `struct` containing both a `short` (or `byte`), and an array, or a hashtable, or some other list look up mechanism, which contains the possible [legal] values that the `short` can take, and then sprinkled around within the rest of your code, you write access funtions which assign values to the `short` which *only* correspond to values which are held in the String array.

However, this latter option is obviously the same as a class, but with its methods *external* to the object. After all, the simple definition of a class is a struct which contains its own methods.